# A bag contains 5 red, 6 blue, and 4 yellow marbles

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorics-on-words

A. How many ways can marbles be drawn if at least 1 must be drawn?

**What I’ve done to attempt to solve this question A.**

*Just imagine that the marbles aren’t actually marbles, but rather switches. The first 5 switches are representative of “red marbles” and if all 5 of them are switched on, then you have taken all your red marbles. The next 6 are marked blue, and so forth therefore the remaining 4 are yellow. How many ways can the switches be setup? 2^15, so therefore 32,768. However the question asks that you must select at least one marble, so you can’t switch all the switches to off, and so there would be one less, 32,767 ways*

However, I am not sure if my approach is correct because due to the wording of the question I believe that order does not matter and therefore my analogy is incorrect.

I don’t believe it matters if you drew 2 marbles first or last or as the 6th and 7th, as 2 marbles would still be 2 marbles. Therefore, the answer might be a lot less than 32,767.

How do I proceed?

The second question is:

B.) How many ways can 5 marbles be drawn if at least 2 are the same colour?
With this question I am completely stuck.

**The third and final question I am asking as more of a check rather than help.**

C.) How many ways can 5 marbles be drawn out at random of at least one of them were yellow?
*My answer: (15 Choose 5) - (11 Choose 5) = 15!/(5!*10!) - 11!/(5!*6!) = 1/5!*[(15*14*13*12*11) - (11*10*9*8*7)] = (11/5!)*[(15*14*13*12 - 10*9*8*7)] = 11/120*[ 32760 - 5040] = 27720*11/120 = 2772*11/12 = 231*11 = 2541 ways*

I’d appreciate the help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.  Please don't put the narrative in italics.  It conflicts with math italics, and makes it hard to read.

Comment: It think that they mean how may combinations of colors you can have.  So the red marbles are indistinguishable, and so are the marbles of the other colors.  That means you should use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Hint for A): How many red / blue / yellow marbles did you draw?

Comment: @saulspatz I don't think Stars and Bars help here. We're not directly putting $n$ indistinguishable balls into $k$ distinguishable bins. (Yes, there's some interpretation with $k=2$ multiple times, that's in line with my hint)

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, I think you are right.  I spoke too soon.

Comment: @saulspatz Actually, parts B and C are much easier with stars and bars.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the order of drawing is not important. IE We just care about which marbles we have drawn.
If order is important, please state that.

Hint for A): How many red / blue / yellow marbles did you draw?

> $ 6 \times 7 \times 5 - 1 $

Hint for B): If you draw 5 marbles, then at least 2 of them must be the same color. Thus the additional condition is a red herring.

Note that we cannot draw 5 yellow marbles.

> $ {7 \choose 2} - 1$

Hint for C): This is a standard Stars and Bars question.

> { 6 \choose 2 }

Comment: Hi Calvin, Thank you for the hints. For example, would A’s answer simply be your given equation solved? Therefore, 209?

Comment: Also Calvin, could you elaborate on B? I don’t understand why it is not 14, as I brute forced all possible combinations and there were only 14.

Comment: @JohnathanB.Abbott Please show your work and thought processes. My answer for B is wrong, I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Calvin Lin on part A  - the only decision here on an unordered choice is how many of each colour we draw, and $5\times 6\times 4$ allows the drawing of zero marbles, so we just need to exclude that one option, $5\times 6\times 4-1$.

For part B, we need to think about the different combinations that are possible for $5$ marbles. I don't understand why the "at least $2$ of the same colour" condition is present, since this is inevitably fulfilled. We can use a [sticks & stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) approach and just remove the ineligible option of $5$ yellow marbles. For variety I'll build it up from the different *multiplicity* options - we can have $5x$, $4x+y$, $3x+2y$, $3x+y+z$ and $2x+2y+z$ marbles for some combination of marble colours $x,y,z$.
We can choose these the following ways:

- $5x: 2$ options (not yellow)
- $4x+y: 3\times 2 = 6$ options
- $3x+2y: 3\times 2 = 6$ options
- $3x+y+z: 3$ options (choose $x$)
- $2x+2y+z: 3$ options (choose $z$)

giving a total of $20$ options, agreeing with the $\binom 72-1$ version. The detail breakdown approach above is useful if we also have to think about order.

Picking the relevant parts of this detail to answer part C, the $4x+y$ and $3x+2y$ options reduce to $4$ options (pick which slot is yellow, choose the other colour) and $5x$ vanishes, giving $14$ options.